# Laravel mix, extract not decreasing app.js

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I have set up my project like this:

webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['seisplotjs-waveformplot', 'seisplotjs-fdsnstation'])
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

my app.js starts like so:

```
import {d3} from "seisplotjs-waveformplot";
import {StationQuery} from "seisplotjs-fdsnstation";

require('./bootstrap');
```

I'm not importing any other libraries in app.js
Problem is when I run npm run dev I get the following results:

```
          Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   /css/app.css   139 KiB       0  [emitted]         /js/app
     /js/app.js  1.52 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
/js/manifest.js  1.42 KiB       1  [emitted]         /js/manifest
  /js/vendor.js   1.5 MiB       2  [emitted]  [big]  /js/vendor
```

So it did build my vendors but my app.js is still huge. Why does it not decrease the size of my app.js file?

Comment: Are you building dev or production?

Comment: Even when building for production, it behaves the same way.